# Multi-threading Spring Transaction

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-transactions

Assume that we go inside a method and start a transaction in main thread. In this method, there are some async methods so we created 2 more threads inside this method;

```
                 Thread 1 --> SubMethod1 --> Saving (t=1)
                   ^
                   |
MainThread --> MainMethod --> Saving (t=3)
                   |
                   v   
                 Thread 2 --> SubMethod2 --> Exception while saving (t=2).
```

Since thread 2 gets an exception, I want to rollback all transactions done by other threads. However, although transactions owned by main thread an Thread 2 can be roll-backed, I cannot roll-back thread 1 work.
I am using Spring/Hibernate, so do you have any idea to manage this and how to apply?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use threads. Transactions are thread bound and you have multiple transactions. You cannot rollback a committed transaction. The only "solution" would be to manually undo the work (deleting records, restoring old state etc.).

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30091149/3971900

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From **Professional Java for Web Applications** by Nicholas S. Williams

The transaction scope in Spring is limited to the thread the transaction begins in. The transaction manager then links the transaction to managed resources used in the same thread during the life of the transaction. When using the Java Persistence API, the resource you work with is the `EntityManager`. It is the functional equivalent of Hibernate ORM’s Session and JDBC’s Connection. Normally, you would obtain an `EntityManager` from the `EntityManagerFactory` before beginning a transaction and performing JPA actions. However, this does not work with the Spring Framework model of managing transactions on your behalf. The solution to this problem is the `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean`. When you configure JPA in Spring Framework, it creates a `SharedEntityManagerBean` that proxies the `EntityManager` interface. This proxy is then injected into your JPA repositories. When an `EntityManager` method is invoked on this proxy instance, the following happens in the background:

➤➤ If the current thread already has a real `EntityManager` with an active transaction, it delegates the call to the method on that `EntityManager`.

➤➤ Otherwise, Spring Framework obtains a new `EntityManager` from the `EntityManagerFactory`, starts a transaction, and binds both to the current thread. It then delegates the call to the method on that `EntityManager`. When the transaction is either committed or rolled back, Spring unbinds the transaction and the  `EntityManager` from the thread and then closes the `EntityManager`. Future `@Transactional` actions on the same thread (even within the same request) start the process over again, obtaining a new `EntityManager` from the factory and beginning a new transaction. This way, no two threads use an `EntityManager` at the same time, and a given thread has only one transaction and one `EntityManager` active at any given time.

If you were ***not*** to use Spring MVC then you would have gotten the session using `SessionFactory` in Hibernate. Hibernate Sessions represent the life of a transaction from start to finish. Depending on how your application is architected, that might be less than a second or several minutes; and in a web application, it could be one of several transactions in a request, a transaction lasting an entire request, or a transaction spanning multiple requests. A `Session`, which is not thread-safe and must be used only in one thread at a time, is responsible for managing the state of entities.

Comment: So let's say an endpoint needs to `DELETE FROM` 3 tables, and then `INSERT INTO` those same 3 tables. The insertions need `SELECT` from 2 other unrelated tables. There would be no way to multithread this endpoint by issuing all the `DELETE`s together (each table request executed in a separate thread) along with the `SELECT`s (again: one thread per DB request), followed by a blocking call that awaits all the results to finally issue `INSERT`s in their own thread? (All this for a total of 5 threads handling all 8 requests, instead of one thread doing this whole work sequentially.)

Comment: @payne I am not in a position to answer this question at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This post https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management-over-multiple-thread-1 appears to cover the issue quite well and mentions a project that is doing something similar.